# Kendo UI Diagram: Customize Item template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm facing challenges on customizing the Kendo-UI Diagram component. The customization is to bring some options (Context menu) on Items. Sample is shown in the below diagram.

[image]

When I click on the above icon, the context menu should popup. Example is shown below.

[image]

on Click on the options, I suppose to bring some dialog box. The complete sample can be seen below.

[image: demo]

The above one is the wire-frame. Is't possible to achieve the same in Diagram?

Appreciate your support.

Comment: It's already 3 years old, but have you found a solution?